# Sorting with SortableDataProvider and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, wicket

I have the following code:

PersonDao.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDao implements PersonDaoIface {

Object property;
String order;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public PersonDao() {

}

public PersonDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Person> getAll(long first, long count) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
    this.setPaging(criteria, first, count);
    addSort(criteria);
    return criteria.list();
}

@Override
public long getAllCount() {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    Long i = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return i;
}

@Override
public List<Person> getByFilter(Person person, int first, int count) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", person.getFirstName()));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("lastName", person.getLastName()));
    this.setPaging(criteria, first, count);
    return criteria.list();
}

@Override
public long getByFilterCount(Person person) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", person.getFirstName()));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("lastName", person.getLastName()));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    Long result = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return result;
}

private void setPaging(Criteria criteria, long first, long count) {
    criteria.setFirstResult((int) first);
    criteria.setMaxResults((int) count);
}

private void addSort(Criteria criteria) {
    if (property != null) {
        if (order.equalsIgnoreCase(SortOrder.ASCENDING.toString())) {
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc((String)property));
        } else {
            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc((String)property));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setSort(Object property, String order) {
    this.property = property;
    this.order = order;
}
```

}

SortableDataProvider

```
public class PersonSortableDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider {

private transient PersonDaoIface personDao;

public PersonSortableDataProvider(PersonDaoIface personDao) {
    this.personDao = personDao;

}

public PersonSortableDataProvider() {
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Iterator<Person> iterator(long first, long count) {
    System.out.println(getSort());
    return personDao.getAll(first, count).iterator();
}

@Override
public long size() {
    long result = personDao.getAllCount();
    return result;
}

@Override
public IModel<Person> model(final Object object) {
    return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person getObject() {
            return (Person) object;
        }
    };
}
```

}

A panel with a data table using the sortable data provider

```
public DataDisplayPanel(String id) {
    super(id);

    List<IColumn> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn>();
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("First Name"), "firstName"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("Last Name"), "lastName"));

    AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable table = new AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable("personData", columns,
            personSortableDataProvider, 8);
    table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, personSortableDataProvider));
    add(table);
}
```

I have paging done no problem but I am having trouble understanding how to get sorting working with hibernate, I can see how you could do the sorting from the java side of things but given that I could potentially get large data sets back I don't like this idea.

Given my code above does anyone have a way of getting the data table, on click of either first name or last name to then make the same query found in the iterator with the additional order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need an:

```
addOrder(Order.asc(columnName))
```

The doc is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-ordering).

Comment: Yes i have finally added this but when i click the column headers to change the order the getSort().getProperty() and isAscending values do not change, any ideas ?

Comment: I have added the extra argument for sorting in the PropertyColumns for reference.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that encounters this situation I have the following setup:

hibernate 4, spring 4 and wicket 6

I inject using Spring and it seems wicket and spring get confused if you inject within the SortableDataProvider.

I don't know what exactly happens; when i step over the project I will have a better idea but it appears setSort is not getting set correctly, when i move the Dao class out of sortable data provider and into the page and inject it there, then pass the dao instance into sortable data provider the sorting works correctly.